# How do I determine what a function will be called if it's virtual and when it is not?

Tags: c++, oop

Look at this excerpt of a program.

I see that `cout << obj->foo();` call is not polymorphic. Actually, it is obvious, because it has no `virtual` specificator.

But I am confused with `cout << ((B*)obj)->foo();` Why the program does not use the `B`'s definition of virtual function and will call the third version of `foo()`?

```
 #include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 

class A{ 
public:     
    int foo(){ return 1; } 
}; 
class B: public A{ 
public:     
    virtual int foo(){ return 2; } 
}; 
class C: public B{ 
public:     
    int foo(){ return 3; } 
}; 

int main() {  
    A* obj = new C; 

    cout << obj->foo(); 
    cout << ((B*)obj)->foo(); 
    cout << ((C*)obj)->foo(); 

    return 0;  
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `((B*)obj)->foo();` behaves by design like `B* b = (B*)obj; b->foo()` and calls `C::foo`. You may call the base's method explicitly like `((B*)obj)->B::foo();`.

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 

class A{ 
public:     
    int foo(){ return 1; } 
}; 
class B: public A{ 
public:     
    virtual int foo(){ return 2; } 
}; 
class C: public B{ 
public:     
    int foo() override { return 3; } 
}; 

int main() {  
    A* obj = new C; 

    cout << obj->foo();
    cout << ((B*)obj)->B::foo(); 
    cout << ((C*)obj)->foo(); 

    return 0;  
}
```

Output: 123

Comment: This explanation is very helpful. I havn't come up with idea that ```(B*)``` would be as ```B* b = (B*)obj; b->foo()```, thank you!

Answer (score 6):

`A::foo()` is not `virtual`.  Calling `foo()` via an `A*` pointer (or `A&` reference) will call `A::foo()` directly without any polymorphic dispatch.

`B::foo()` is `virtual`.  Calling `foo()` via a `B*` pointer (or `B&` reference) will dispatch the call to the most derived implementation of `foo()` that exists in the object that the `B*` (or `B&`) refers to.

`C` derives from `B`, and `C::foo()` overrides `B::foo()`, and `obj` points to a `C` object, which is why `C::foo()` gets called by polymorphic dispatch when `foo()` is called via a `B*` or `C*` pointer (or a `B&` or `C&` reference).

Answer (score 3):

Member function `foo` is virtual from class `B` downwards, i.e. also in `C`, even if it is not marked `virtual` or `override` there.

Thus, call `((B*)obj)->foo()` is a virtual call, actually resulting in calling `C::foo`.